# I've have some problems with connectiong to server. written on ASP .NET Core, on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, asp.net-core

I am creating some chat app in Android Studio and i have server, written on ASP .NET core.
I've used SignalR. but there is a few information about it. 
What i can use on a client side to connect to the server, and make some requests and responses.

Comment: Here's a starting point https://medium.com/@sotti/android-networking-ii-okhttp-retrofit-moshi-and-picasso-c381f6c0efd8 - there are many ways of baking this cake, you need to evaluate which works best for your application

Comment: You did not tell where your server is running. Nor did you tell where your client is running.

Comment: server is working on my computer, client on android

Comment: Well.. what is the problem? Let the client connect.

Comment: I am not famillar with SignalR But you could use httpconnection or httpsConnection class for connecting to a server and by writing of wcf restful services(written with visual studio) you could calling the services in your mobile app.There is many samples using wcf restfull services for getting or writing data . If you want to use a utility for connections , you only need implementation of your code without implementing of your connection class.